# Does running scripts from Cloud (AWS/Google/Azure) make my algorithms faster?

Tags: python, cloud

Hello I have designed some algorithms that we would like to implement in our company's software (start-up) but some of them take too long (10-15 min) as it is handling big datasets.

I am wondering if using for example Google Cloud to run my scripts, as it would use more nodes, it would make my algorithm to run faster.

Is it the same to run a script locally in Jupyter for instance than running it within Cloud?
Thinking of using Spark too.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think the only applicable answer is "it depends". The cloud is just "someone else's computer", so if it runs faster or not depends on the cloud server it's running on. For example if it is a data-intensive task with a lot of I/O it might run faster on a server with a SSD than on your local machine with a HDD. If it's a processor intensive task, it might run faster if the server has a faster CPU than your local machine has. You get the point.